# Windows batch script multiple monitors

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to launch an application on a specific monitor through windows batch scripts? Also, is it possible to send virtual keystrokes? If not which is the best way to do this task?

Comment: Not through plain cmd.exe. You'd need to shell out to a different app to do that sort of stuff.

Comment: And which is the best way to do this? An app is a good alternative.

Comment: AutoHotKey for the keystrokes. You can almost certainly use that to put the app on the desired screen also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3518/Executing-programs-remotely-in-Windows-NT-2000-XP) for remote execution and [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27589) for keystrokes.

(I think you should be able to use SSH also execute a program remotely. Needs SSH server on the remote system.)

Comment: He doesn't want remote execution, he want's to open it on a secondary monitor.

Comment: I think that AutoHotKey is the best choice for my task. I am going to post an answer once I have the script done and running.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolute no way of doing this currently with Batch. Windows would patch that the minute it got out.

But you could run a program that connects to another users computer. Using the

```
CALL *program name + Extension*
```